# robot (PR2) physical information

Tags: ros, robot, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I've been working with lasers for laser avoidance, and because of the [Eigen/Core bug](http://answers.ros.org/question/198257/laser-geometry-and-eigencore-bug-how-to-actually-fix-it/), I skipped using a Laser projector and did the computation of tilt scan into base scan by hand. Rotation is ok, I still need to translate my data between frames (robot tilt height to robot base height, etc.). So I would know if a physical description of the robot (base width, length of joints) is available or I should define myself the distances I need (by measuring, which is the worst solution).

Of course, if you are able to answer my question on Eigen/Core, that would be the best option, imho.

Thanks,
Erwan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198539/robot-(pr2)-physical-information/) by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on ROS Answers with karma: 697 on 2014-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. You should really be able to use TF for this, to transform points from one frame to another.
2. That Eigen bug looks suspiciously old. You probably aren't running into the same issue as the original author. I'll respond there.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2014-11-28**:
Your solution on Eigen/Core post worked fine for me.